# Why does the font size go giant?

Tags: textarea, codenameone

in the simulator;

There seems to be a default style that pops the size of the text in
a TextArea to double while the mouse is down to select it.

Where is this determined and how should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The designer has unselected and selected styles (also pressed for buttons etc.)

Copy the settings you made for the unselected state (the first tab) into the second tab for the selected states and it should make it behave as expected.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the designer.  I have no designer - this is a port of a UI that is already designed.   It seems like a poor choice that the default state of selected and unselected styles is so different.

Comment: Its not the default state. I assume you used something like `getStyle().setFont(...)`? In that case you should have used `getAllStyles().setFont(...)`. If you had included the full information in the question you would have gotten a better answer.

Comment: In this case I never set any font at all, I just accepted all defaults.